# Validate paths using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am asking users to enter path to controller files like

```
abc/cab
cde/ter/tyu
```

I am unable to validate it using

```
var regexString =/^([a-zA-Z\]+)*$/;
```

Can you please help me correct this. text like `abc//text` and `abc/text/` and `abc/text//` and `/abc/text` also should return false. There should be no slash at beginning and ending also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
var regexString = /^([a-z]+\/)*[a-z]+$/i;
```

Will work for:

```
abc/cab
abc/cab/bla
```

but won't for:

```
abc/cab/
/abc/cab
/abc/cab/
abc//sdgf
abc//sdgf/
/abc//sdgf
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine:

```
var regexString =/^[a-zA-Z]+(\/[a-zA-Z]+)*$/;
```

And will match

```
abc
abc/cab
cde/ter/ger
```

But not

```
/abc/sucks
abc//text
abc/text/
abc/text//
```

Comment: @ h2ooooooo - But its allowing text like abc//text and abc/text/ and abc/text// also. How do i prevent this

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regular expression which is going to match a string with parameters you described:

```
/^([a-zA-Z]+\/[a-zA-Z]+)+$/
```

Here is an example:

```
var r = /^([a-zA-Z]+\/[a-zA-Z]+)+$/;
r.test('/ad/sd'); //false
r.test('as//sd'); //false
r.test('as/sd/'); //false
r.test('as/sd'); //true
```